# Changing mail for notifications in Preferences doesn't notify about sending a confirmation mail

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, email

When I insert a new email address here:

[image]

After pressing "Save email settings", the button changes its color to grey and the user think that it's done.

When you leave this page, and come back to it again, you'll note that your old mail is back.

It turns out that a confirmation mail was sent to my old mail and need to be confirmed in order to save the newly entered mail. There is **no** message shown from the page above telling me I should check my mail (although I was sure there must be a confirmation mail).

It's a little bit confusing and sometimes a user might think his email was changed until he visit the page again.

I think there should be a message indicating that a confirmation is needed and a mail was sent to your inbox.

The same issue happens when you update your career profile, there's no notification that a mail was sent to your inbox and the UI doesn't change. It's really hard to tell if the operation was done successfully.

<sup>I'm not sure if this post should be tagged "bug" or "feature-request"</sup>

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to me - nothing obvious that says it isn't working as intended (right now).

Comment: A simple `alert` would do it...

Comment: A confirmation mail was sent to the **old** mail address? That seems wrong. If there is a confirmation mail, it should definitely go to the *new* address.

Comment: @sth I assume they send it to the old address so you have to opportunity to reject the change if it wasn't you who tried to change it.

Comment: @sth It was sent to the new mail.