# Notification sent to incorrect email address

Tags: bug, notifications, email

My profile email address is abc@myemail.com but I get notification to email xyz@someoneelseemail.com. Why is this?

I think the problem started because more than one person use the same computer and for some reason stackoverflow at one point tried to lump all different logins into one account.... its been a while so I am not sure what the issue was but maybe that created this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The change mail configuration is very confusing, see my feature-request here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296423/changing-mail-for-notifications-in-preferences-doesnt-notify-about-sending-a-co

Comment: @Kendra: My profile already has the correct email. The other email (the one I get notifications to) is nowhere to be seen in my profile. It is not even my email.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I added your link to my answer with a note to check it out. If you feel like there should be more added to it, please, feel free to edit.

Comment: Where I pointed you to is where notification settings are, well, set. If the email there is correct, then yes, that is a likely bug. That's a hard one to confirm, though, as 1) SO users don't know what email is on your profile versus what's getting notification and 2) You can't really (or at least shouldn't) post your emails and a screenshot to prove this. This one _might_ require contacting the team directly. (Double check and make sure you were going to the right spot. You can have a different notification email than the one shown in the "Edit Profile" section of your settings.)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the way the system is currently behaving. You have the same email set in both places. If it's being sent somewhere else, then please [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and include the email where it was sent and preferably a complete copy of the message that was sent so we can look into what's happening. The information provided here simply isn't enough to figure anything out.

Comment: @animuson: Are you sure the email address is the same? We all have basically identical emails, the only thing that changes is one or two letter at the beginning of the email address. Could you double check and verify that both emails are truly indeed identical?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a residual effect of an incorrect merge attempt, but it's something you can fix on your own.

Go to your profile, and you should see these tabs at the top:

[image: Tabs at the top of the profile page]

Click on "Edit Profile & Settings" to go to your account settings. (Note: This will just read "Settings" on your Meta profile.) You should see these options:

[image: Options under Settings]

You want "Preferences" this time. That will take you to your various account preferences. At the top, you'll see your email settings:

[image: Email settings]

Check the email here and make sure it's correct, or change it if it's not.

<sub>In the comments, Maroun Maroun brought up [Changing mail for notifications in Preferences doesn't notify about sending a confirmation mail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296423/changing-mail-for-notifications-in-preferences-doesnt-notify-about-sending-a-co) concerning a potential issue with changing your email here. I advise checking it out as well.</sub>

Comment: The problem is that my profile already has the correct email. I have no idea where the other email is stored at.

Comment: Are you getting notification of messages from your inbox, or lists of questions on the site? Because there's another spot I realized that this could be getting set at, but as far as my (admittedly quick) test can tell, you  only get question lists from that setting.

Comment: I normally don't get any notifications at all (even though my profile says to get notifications). This time (not sure why) I got one notification from an old post. My guess is that notifications are being sent out I have no idea what email address is getting those notifications,

Comment: Only _unread_ notifications get sent. If you get on and read your notifications before the email would be sent, you don't get the email. Have you confirmed that emails for your account are going to another email?

Comment: @T555 You've only got one email as far as I can see... at one point you requested an email for account recovery - did that reach you? (Kind of guessing so as you're logged in...)

Comment: Yes, I was told that a notification for one of my post was sent to some else email.

Comment: @T555 not quite sure I understand - told by whom/what?

Comment: @Jon Clements: Yes it did. This appears to be a notification problem only.

Comment: @T555 Are you sure it was from Stack Overflow and not a different site? Did you check your email settings on other sites you have an account on? If yes to all... I'm not sure what any normal users can do for you, as that does sound like some strange bug and would probably need a dev to look at.

Comment: @JonClements I would assume T555 was told by the owner of the other email address.

Comment: @ Kendra: I am pretty sure it comes from stackoverflow. Its says it is from stackoverflow, It has a link back to the post and some add about and android app.

Comment: @ Kendra: Actually, recovery procedure emails appear to be sent to the correct place. This appears to be a post notification issue only (as far as I can see).

Comment: @T555 If you're looking at it on mobile, that's likely why you see the android app ad. If the link back to the post links to your one SO post, then yes, it's from Stack Overflow. You do have a comment on that post from yesterday, so if you haven't changed your email settings since then... I think this is where a dev would have to come in.